# Is there a succinct way to split this negative integer into a list of digits? (Python)

Tags: list, split, integer, negative-number, negative-integer

I can do this using an if statement but I feel like the code is too long for this simple operation.

**num = -12345**

-->*inserts magical code*<--

*desired output*

**num_list = ['-1', '2', '3', '4', '5']**

Comment: I have been coding for 20 years, 
I did need to convert a number into a string hundreds of time.
I did need to convert a string into an array of characters hundreds of time.
I never needed to convert into an array of characters where the fist character would also contain the sign.
it is not a common operation at all.
So I doubt you'll fine a library for this.
You'll have to write your "if" !!
What language is it?

Comment: python, its for question on a quiz

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `.split("\\B")`

So the magical code would be:

```
String[] num_list = Integer.toString(num).split("\\B");
```

Comment: NameError: name 'Integer' is not defined, is Integer an imported function?

Comment: @AdamZawitkowski I've answered in Java... "\\B" is a regular expression, you can check how to do the same in Python...

Comment: Belated thank you for the answer @Juliano